# How to remove left header on all glossary pages?

Tags: header-footer, glossaries

I am using the glossary package for my PhD thesis. It works fine for me, but there is one little thing I want to change. On every glossary page, there is "Glossary" appear on the top left. It also appears in my reference page, since I put print the glossary before the reference. My question is how can I remove that word "glossary"?

I searched around, tried this:

```
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{}
```

I intend to remove the left heading for every page. But it doesn't work.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

---

I am using the package `glossary` in my preamble I have:

```
\usepackage{glossary}
\makeglossary
```

In the text where I put my glossary page I used this command:

```
% this is adding my glossary into TOC
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textmd{Glossary}}
% this is print out my glossary page
\printglossary
```

After the glossary I have my reference. To generate the glossary, after generating the PDF file from LyX, I have to run these commands:

```
makeindex phd_thesis.glo -s phd_thesis.ist -t phd_thesis.glg -o phd_thesis.gls
pdflatex phd_thesis.tex
pdflatex phd_thesis.tex
```

Every page on glossary and reference shows a "Glossary" on top left.

I am thinking before the `\printglossary` command  put some command to get rid of the left heading. I searched around, haven't find any solution yet.

I am using LaTeX 2.9 and LyX 2.0.

Comment: Please compose a simple document showing the relevant settings (the document class used, the packages relevant to your problem, and an skeleton showing how you build the glossary and the bibliography) and add it to your question.

Comment: Perhaps if you set the glossary name to empty things should work: `\renewcommand*{\glossaryname}{}`

Comment: The `glossary` package is obsolete; use the [`glossaries`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) package instead.

Answer (score 2):

The `glossary` package is obsolete. So I’d recommend upgrading to its (much advanced) successor, the [`glossaries`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) package (see [this guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossary2glossaries.pdf)).

If I understand you right you want to get rid of the running header in the glossary section. Using the `glossaries` package, you can achieve this by redefining `\glossarymark` as an empty macro. Minimal example:

```
%% Process with pdflatex <document>; makeglossaries <document>; pdflatex <document>.

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{Test}{name={Test}, description={A Test}}

\renewcommand*{\glossarymark}[1]{}

\begin{document}

\printglossary

\newpage\gls{Test}\newpage\gls{Test}

\end{document}
```